# how to use select sub query in other query MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am writing a mysql select sub query, that is working fine, it returns 2 column is there way to select only 1 column.
My query is

```
SELECT sum(fl.qunt) as qunt,(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( xp.id
    SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
    FROM prdt AS xp
    LEFT JOIN prdt_fac AS pf ON pf.fk_product_children = xp.rowid
    WHERE pf.prdt_fat = p.id
    AND pf.prdt_ch = 6953
    GROUP BY pf.prdt_fat
    LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) AS prdt_chd
    FROM fac_log AS fl
    LEFT JOIN fac AS f ON fl.fac = f.id
    LEFT JOIN prdt AS p ON f.prdt = p.id
    GROUP BY prod_child
    ORDER BY fl.tms DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 1
```

This return two column qunt and prdt_ch.
But i want only column in result qunt.
Is there any way, becuase inner select query is must be used to get correct result.
Main purpose of this query is that i have to use this query as sub query in an other query, in this condition it throws error "operand should contain 1 column"
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just select qunt using your select  query as a table (t)

```
  select qunt from ( 
        SELECT sum(fl.qunt) as qunt,(
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( xp.id
            SEPARATOR  ',' ) 
            FROM prdt AS xp
            LEFT JOIN prdt_fac AS pf ON pf.fk_product_children = xp.rowid
            WHERE pf.prdt_fat = p.id
            AND pf.prdt_ch = 6953
            GROUP BY pf.prdt_fat
            LIMIT 0 , 1
            ) AS prdt_chd
            FROM fac_log AS fl
            LEFT JOIN fac AS f ON fl.fac = f.id
            LEFT JOIN prdt AS p ON f.prdt = p.id
            GROUP BY prod_child
            ORDER BY fl.tms DESC  
      LIMIT 0 , 1 ) t
```